# Why users are no longer members of active directory group after few minutes?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, membership

I am adding users to an active directory group using C# code after performing some operations. I verified that the users are listed in the 'Members' tab of that security Group.
A couple of minutes later, I opened again the same group properties and most of the users are no longer there. Is this normal? How come? Are there some properties or timeout or session specific things do associated. ( But to be honest all these users have the same settings on their 'Session' and 'Account' tabs. I verified these settings by opening for the users that are still the part of that group and compared with the members which are no longer the part of the group any more.

Can anybody let me know?

Comment: Is there an identity manager system (such as MIM) managing AD?

Comment: Nops, I have no idea about it. I am very new to AD. So it's quite strange for me to see that added users are no longer the part of Security Group after a minute or so later.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this, looks likely that the group membership is being controlled by a Group Policy in Active Directory. Depending on your access you may be able to view or update the policy, or you may need someone's help. If you Google the above terms you will find tons of links that will explain much better than I can - good luck!

Comment: Not every member got removed. Only 2 of them still remained as added in the group while 6 removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guys.

I verified. The problem was there was another process going on which was removing the users from Active Directory which were basically created at different 'Ou' level. This process was checking the membership of the users and finally removing the users from security group.

Answer (score 2):

If you wait longer (more than 15 minutes) are the members there?

It is possible that you are reading from a different domain controller than the one you made the change on. It will take time for the change to replicate to the other domain controllers.

If you still don't see the members after a while, then something else removed them. That doesn't happen by itself.

Or maybe you didn't actually add them properly. You can update your question with the code you are using if you want help there.

Comment: I will post code at monday and will update post accordinly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, most likely due to AD Group Policy managing the group membership.

Comment: The funny thing is not every member got removed. Only 2 left among 8 members. So 6 users were entirely removed from the 'Members' tab of the group.